# Struggling with CONTAINS (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to search through a column in one table (Asset_Database_Current) with the details from a column in another table (DNI_Names). I've written a loop to go through each DNI_Name, and then a SELECT CONTAINS statement to (hopefully) compare DNI_Name against the relevant column in Asset_Database_Current.

I've set up a FullText Catalog and have indexed the Asset_Database_Current table to be searchable.

This is the code I have:

```
DECLARE
   @Asset varchar(8)
 , @software_Name VARCHAR(64)
 , @dniSW VARCHAR(64)
 , @DNI VARCHAR(64)

CREATE TABLE #temp_naughtyChildren (naughtyAsset CHAR(8), naughtySW VARCHAR(64))
-- ^ where the Naughty People eventually get put

DECLARE #dni_cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT DNI_Names.DNI_Name
FROM DNI_Names
OPEN #dni_cur
FETCH NEXT FROM #dni_cur 
INTO @DNI

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN -- we go through DNI_Names, selecting each instance of DNI_Name one at a time...

    INSERT INTO #temp_naughtyChildren (naughtyAsset, naughtySW)
    SELECT Asset_Number, Software_Name
    FROM Asset_Database_Current
    WHERE CONTAINS (Asset_Database_Current.Software_Name, @DNI)

    FETCH NEXT FROM #dni_cur 
    INTO @DNI

END 

DEALLOCATE #dni_cur

-- #temp_NaughtyChildren is now full of all the Asset Numbers and swName's of people who 
--  have been very, very naughty. The table can now be used as required (emailed, sent to 
--  another d/b, etc.).
 SELECT * from #temp_NaughtyChildren ORDER BY naughtyAsset

DROP TABLE #temp_naughtyChildren

END
GO
```

The above code completes successfully, but when I try and execute the query I get the following error twice:

> Msg 7630, Level 15, State 3, Procedure DNIChecker, Line 44
>   Syntax error near 'Manager' in the full-text search condition 'App Manager'.

My boss has also executed the query (he has full permissions on the database) and he gets the exact same error.

Any suggestions you can give me will be very gratefully received (I haven't done SQL since 1998, I've realised that when they teach you SQL at Uni they don't actually teach you much SQL, and I have spent the last 2 1/2 weeks trawling various sites working on this. Only yesterday did I finally stumble across an article that mentioned there was a wizard to set up full-text search!!).

Thanks, M

Comment: I think your loop is superfluous, since you search for one keyword at a time (seems that way, correct?) you could just search for multiple keywords at once by connecting them via `OR` as @pln also mentions in his answer (you might not want to lose the loop if you want to have duplicate entries for results if the same row could be found using different search terms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CONTAINS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787(v=sql.100).aspx) require qoutes around the search condition if you use a full phrase, otherwise you should use NEAR, AND, OR between the single words.

```
SET @DNI = '"' + @DNI + '"';
INSERT INTO #temp_naughtyChildren (naughtyAsset, naughtySW)
SELECT Asset_Number, Software_Name
FROM Asset_Database_Current
WHERE CONTAINS (Asset_Database_Current.Software_Name, @DNI)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that give me:
"Incorrect syntax near '+'."

Comment: Sorry, I modified the answer

Comment: That didn't work the first time (for some reason, although I suspect that SQL Server 2008 is operated by tiny moody Gremlins), but it did work the second time. Thank you very much indeed for all of your help pln!!!